# identityServer - can't work with 2 tabs of 2 clients because of regeneration of token

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

i'm having the following issue: I have 2 clients with one identity server connected. User is logged in.
when client 1 is opened on tab 1. and from client 1 i open a link in new tab to client 2. In this moment the client 2 sends a request to identity Server to ask about the token and it responses successfully. now i have client 1 opened in tab 1 and client 2 opened in tab 2.

now i go back to tab 1 and try to make a fetch request, the request fails, because the token is old. i have to reload the page in order to renew the token.

following error i can find in the logs:

```
2022-12-15 13:57:33.6372|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://srv/administration/details?handler=ChecktName application/json; charset=UTF-8 74
2022-12-15 13:57:33.6372|7|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
2022-12-15 13:57:33.6372|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService|Authorization failed.
2022-12-15 13:57:33.6372|12|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler|AuthenticationScheme: oidc was challenged.
2022-12-15 13:57:33.6372|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request finished in 1.6358ms 302
```

I thought it could be a problem with data protection. so added following code in startup configuration:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     ....
     services.AddDataProtection();
     ....
  }
```

But it didn't work. Any idea how can i solve this?

############# Edit#########
IdentityServer and all clients are running on same server with different ports wit same domain name.

############ Edit 2 ########
I have checked the refresh token and i found out, that it was regenerated in the new tab. That's why the first tab has an expired refresh-Token.

Configuration of IdentityServer:

```
services
        .AddIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions)
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
        .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetScoops())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients()))



public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfigurationSection section)
      {
     var clients = new List<Client>();

     var eClients = new List<PlugIn>();

     section.Bind(eClients);

     foreach (PlugIn plugIn in eClients)
     {
        string lUrl = plugIn.Url;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lUrl) && lUrl.EndsWith("/"))
        {
           lUrl = lUrl.Substring(0, lUrl.Length - 1);
        }

   

        if (plugIn.ClientConfig != null)
        {
           var client = plugIn.ClientConfig;

           client.AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials;

           if (!client.AllowedScopes.Contains(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId))
           {
              client.AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
           }

           if (!client.AllowedScopes.Contains(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile))
           {
              client.AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
           }

           if (!client.AllowedScopes.Contains("roles"))
           {
              client.AllowedScopes.Add("roles");
           }

           client.AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName);

           client.AllowedScopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);

           client.AllowOfflineAccess = true;
           client.FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired = false;
           client.UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true;
           AddOidcSignInUrl(lUrl, client);
           client.RedirectUris.Add(lUrl + "/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html");
           client.PostLogoutRedirectUris.Add(lUrl + "/signout-callback-oidc");
           client.FrontChannelLogoutUri = lUrl + "/Clientlogout";
           client.AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true;
           client.AlwaysSendClientClaims = true;
           client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 86400;
           client.SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 43200;

           if (client.AccessTokenLifetime < 3600)
           {
              client.AccessTokenLifetime = 3600;
           }

           client.RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse;
           client.RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute;
           clients.Add(client);
        }
     }

     return clients;
  }
```

configuration of client:

```
.... 
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
           options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
           options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
        {
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
           options.SlidingExpiration = true;
           options.SessionStore = new DictionaryTicketStore(services);

           options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
           options.Authority = this.CentralHubAdresse;
           options.ClientId = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
           options.ClientSecret ="####";
           options.ResponseType = "code";
           options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

          
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
           options.BackchannelHttpHandler = GetHandler();
           options.Scope.Add("roles");
           options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
           options.Scope.Add("IdentityServerApi");

           options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
           options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
           options.SaveTokens = true;
           options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        });
```

Comment: Are they on the same domain or different domains? You need to describe your setup a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They are on same domain on the same server using different ports.

Comment: Have you looked at using a refresh token to refresh the tokens?

Comment: Not sure how you configured it, but [this article](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3146) may help you, his configuration is still available for a certain period of time after the token is refreshed. Also, [this documentation on refresh tokens](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/refresh/) may also help you.

Comment: @chen thank you for your comment. i have added the configuration of the server and of the client. I hope you can find the problem in it.

Comment: @ToreNestenius I'm using the refresh token and i checked it in the new tab and i found out, that it has been regenerated.

Comment: Do you have separate clientId for both applications? and what is the actual question?

Comment: each client has a separate ClientId yes. The problem is, when i have a tab 1 opened with client 1 and from there i open a new tab with client 2, the refresh-Token will be renewed and the client 1 on tab 1 will have an expired token. 

That could not be a problem if i just have to reload the page. But i do have problem with this, when i send a fetch request because it fails.

Comment: I think the problem is, that the refresh token gets renewed every time i change the active client. Do you know how can i use always the same refresh-Token over all clients as long as it valid? @ToreNestenius

Comment: Each client should receive a separate refresh token. If you use https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , then it can handle the automatic refresh of the refresh tokens for you.

Comment: From the configuration you provided, it seems that there is no problem. Like Tore Nestenius said: Each client should receive a separate refresh token. It's reasonable. Perhaps you can use [AccessTokenManagement](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Duende.AccessTokenManagement) to provide automatic access token management for your application.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Could this because the data protection? I get the provided error just in production but not in the development. 
I think that the added code of AddDataProtection(); didn't imrpove anything.

Comment: DataProtection needs to be configured in production, but if you don't configure it properly, the result is that people might be logged out when you redeploy your application. It also needs to be configured if you want to share session cookie across services.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Do you have an example for the right configuraion of DataProtection? 
Is it not enough to add services.AddDataProtection()? All clients are working on same server.

Comment: I did write a blog post about it (perhaps not your need) https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en  or read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0